# How can I erase the data on a phone with a broken display?

Tags: factory-reset, broken-screen

I have a Samsung Galaxy A40 (a405fn) with a broken display (totally dead: no touch reaction and display completely black). I want to sell the phone for parts, but I need to erase the memory.

When I connect the phone to a PC, it's connected but the folder is empty since I can't unlock the phone. It doesn't have a password to unlock, only to slide to back to unlock. The phone reacts to the buttons' presses. I can turn it on and feel vibrations but I don't hear sound.

How can I erase the data on a phone with a broken display?

Comment: https://findmymobile.samsung.com

Comment: https://google.com/android/devicemanager

Comment: You can try to connect a USB mouse or keyboard to unlock the device then the phone will become visible on the PC.

Comment: i tried mouse to unlock but i have no efect . it might unlock the phone but anyway if i connect pc to phone it will anyway what to confit that i allow data transfer but i cant be sure since im blind :/ maybe i will have luck with this solution but i would need cable for usb c to 2x usb so i can connect mouse/keyboard and pc at the same time